# For Diffie-Hellman keys, using d2i_PublicKey

Tags: c, openssl, diffie-hellman

I am trying to pull in a Diffie-Hellman 2048-bit public key in DER format and convert it into an internal `EVP_PKEY` value using `d2i_PublicKey`. I can do this with the corresponding private key and `d2i_PrivateKey`. And I have no trouble doing both of these tasks with RSA keys. The minimal example is below (OpenSSL header files are necessary to compile the minimal example).

```c
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const uint8_t pub_key_arr[] = {
        0x30, 0x82, 0x02, 0x24, 0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x17,
        0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d,
        0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x08, 0x02,
        0x82, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xc4, 0xbd, 0xfb, 0xb6,
        0x90, 0x55, 0xbe, 0x49, 0x89, 0x4b, 0xff, 0xad,
        0x8f, 0x70, 0xc4, 0xdc, 0x6b, 0xb3, 0x76, 0x72,
        0xf9, 0x25, 0xb8, 0x4e, 0xf1, 0xd4, 0x2f, 0x84,
        0x88, 0xce, 0xfc, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x9f, 0x08, 0x2b,
        0x64, 0x36, 0x43, 0x16, 0x49, 0x91, 0x7f, 0x77,
        0xe8, 0x33, 0xcc, 0xb3, 0x4d, 0x2c, 0x88, 0x6f,
        0xcb, 0x3e, 0xb7, 0xcb, 0xd0, 0xb4, 0x13, 0x9f,
        0x5b, 0xc4, 0xd3, 0x53, 0xc8, 0x26, 0x40, 0x0c,
        0xa4, 0xb4, 0x70, 0xac, 0xe0, 0x6a, 0x28, 0xa7,
        0xfa, 0x66, 0x24, 0x0e, 0x81, 0x9a, 0xea, 0x53,
        0x8b, 0xa0, 0x46, 0x8e, 0xeb, 0x4d, 0x72, 0xbd,
        0xd6, 0x3b, 0x69, 0x29, 0xd3, 0x77, 0xab, 0x48,
        0xa5, 0x04, 0x77, 0xc4, 0x29, 0x7a, 0x15, 0x1a,
        0x88, 0x63, 0x1d, 0x8b, 0xf2, 0x18, 0x51, 0xeb,
        0x8b, 0x16, 0xd1, 0xac, 0xe2, 0xf3, 0xa3, 0x3a,
        0xee, 0x09, 0xfa, 0x54, 0xeb, 0x6f, 0x7c, 0xac,
        0xca, 0x2e, 0x04, 0x16, 0x9e, 0x30, 0x18, 0xea,
        0xfb, 0xff, 0x58, 0x3d, 0xb0, 0xde, 0xd4, 0x22,
        0x2c, 0x43, 0x8b, 0x46, 0x3c, 0xb5, 0xfd, 0xaf,
        0x41, 0xb8, 0x42, 0xeb, 0xcc, 0xc1, 0xa4, 0x1b,
        0x26, 0x03, 0xfc, 0x95, 0x8c, 0x48, 0xf6, 0x36,
        0x28, 0xb5, 0x04, 0x0f, 0xdd, 0xcd, 0xb3, 0x30,
        0xc6, 0x4a, 0x39, 0xf1, 0xf1, 0x62, 0x50, 0x1e,
        0xda, 0xa0, 0x80, 0xb5, 0x37, 0x17, 0x98, 0xc1,
        0xe3, 0x34, 0x16, 0x30, 0x76, 0xfa, 0xf1, 0xe9,
        0xea, 0x8c, 0xdd, 0x82, 0x58, 0x8d, 0x96, 0x35,
        0xf8, 0x4a, 0x30, 0x29, 0x98, 0xea, 0x9c, 0x38,
        0xe2, 0x36, 0xdd, 0x37, 0x4e, 0x7b, 0xb2, 0x5f,
        0x79, 0x3a, 0x93, 0x7e, 0x4e, 0x0d, 0xc4, 0xb4,
        0xc5, 0x77, 0x73, 0x09, 0xa0, 0xa1, 0xea, 0x83,
        0x79, 0x51, 0xca, 0xb0, 0xb1, 0x20, 0xe6, 0x49,
        0xa4, 0x96, 0xda, 0xbf, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03,
        0x82, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x02, 0x82, 0x01, 0x00,
        0x62, 0xde, 0x26, 0x78, 0x2b, 0x5f, 0x99, 0xef,
        0xad, 0x91, 0xff, 0x50, 0x31, 0x17, 0x76, 0xe1,
        0xa8, 0xea, 0xb8, 0xe3, 0xf5, 0x38, 0x1a, 0x77,
        0xcb, 0x91, 0x53, 0xa5, 0x12, 0x8a, 0xac, 0xfd,
        0xb7, 0xcd, 0xcd, 0x4c, 0xb1, 0xf6, 0x00, 0x19,
        0x23, 0xfb, 0x06, 0x69, 0x39, 0x09, 0xee, 0xb5,
        0x6e, 0x19, 0x8b, 0x6b, 0xdd, 0x82, 0xb7, 0x81,
        0x1e, 0x72, 0xd3, 0xd0, 0xc1, 0x8f, 0x22, 0x73,
        0x71, 0x94, 0x2c, 0x4a, 0xac, 0x9f, 0x33, 0x4d,
        0x66, 0xc1, 0x07, 0xa2, 0xd1, 0x21, 0x1b, 0x8a,
        0xed, 0x81, 0x6e, 0xe2, 0xec, 0xda, 0x2d, 0x55,
        0x8e, 0x22, 0xef, 0x7d, 0x5c, 0x48, 0x4c, 0x11,
        0xc4, 0x91, 0xa3, 0xfa, 0x54, 0x98, 0xcf, 0x39,
        0x75, 0x5d, 0x25, 0x41, 0xcd, 0x4d, 0xf8, 0xc7,
        0xfa, 0xbf, 0xee, 0x57, 0x2f, 0xfc, 0xf1, 0x6d,
        0xa4, 0x57, 0xd7, 0x43, 0x05, 0xa3, 0x3b, 0xf5,
        0x17, 0xc6, 0x21, 0x96, 0x5b, 0xcd, 0x3b, 0x93,
        0x68, 0xe6, 0x0e, 0x4e, 0x4a, 0xe8, 0x7b, 0x6e,
        0x14, 0xa1, 0x91, 0x8a, 0x62, 0xae, 0x52, 0xd8,
        0x97, 0x74, 0x84, 0x42, 0x01, 0x8a, 0x7b, 0x87,
        0x2a, 0x03, 0x65, 0x18, 0xd0, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0x53,
        0x27, 0xb5, 0x62, 0xdb, 0x23, 0xdb, 0xb9, 0xa7,
        0xb8, 0x99, 0x67, 0x00, 0xfa, 0x32, 0x57, 0x74,
        0x15, 0x01, 0x90, 0x35, 0xf3, 0xd2, 0xc2, 0x3e,
        0x35, 0xe1, 0x31, 0x5e, 0xb0, 0x20, 0xf0, 0x5f,
        0x73, 0x44, 0x02, 0xcb, 0xfb, 0x6f, 0xc6, 0x7f,
        0x3b, 0x44, 0x5b, 0xdd, 0x8b, 0x81, 0x49, 0xcf,
        0xb8, 0x5b, 0xfa, 0x13, 0x88, 0x2f, 0x8e, 0xde,
        0xa0, 0xc4, 0x0f, 0x4a, 0xe4, 0x4f, 0x90, 0x81,
        0xc7, 0xf4, 0xb7, 0x0c, 0xb6, 0x5e, 0xbb, 0x59,
        0x1d, 0xe9, 0x84, 0x7d, 0x3a, 0x40, 0xb6, 0x2a,
        0x8e, 0x65, 0xb5, 0x60, 0x2c, 0x41, 0x73, 0x7e,
    };
    const uint8_t *pub_key_ptr = pub_key_arr;
    const size_t pub_key_len = sizeof(pub_key_arr);
    EVP_PKEY *pub_key = NULL;
    if (d2i_PublicKey(EVP_PKEY_DH, &pub_key, &pub_key_ptr, pub_key_len) == NULL) {
        printf("Error recovering public key, error code 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am actually getting an error code of `error:0200008A:rsa routines::invalid padding` yet this minimal example is giving me an error code of `error:068000A3:asn1 encoding routines::unknown public key type`. How or why this difference arises is beyond me. Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's very hard saying what's wrong without at least seeing the public key form (which shouldn't be a problem; it is, after all, public, so include the array in your code). That said, I suspect you're using `d2i_PublicKey` where you should be using `d2i_PUBKEY` (I know, it's confusing; just wait until you see the header you have to pull it in with). [See example here](https://godbolt.org/z/ssE5a7hs4).

Answer (score 0):

Using `d2i_PUBKEY` from `openssl/x509.h` instead of `d2i_PublicKey` worked as @WhozCraig suggested.

```c
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const uint8_t pub_key_arr[] = {
        /* 2048-bit DH key */
    };
    const uint8_t *pub_key_ptr = pub_key_arr;
    const size_t pub_key_len = sizeof(pub_key_arr);
    EVP_PKEY *pub_key = NULL;
    if (d2i_PUBKEY(&pub_key, &pub_key_ptr, pub_key_len) == NULL) {
        printf("Error recovering public key, error code 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```